# Get notified when an Eclipse IJavaProject's classpath can be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin which, on startup, needs to go through all open Java projects in the workspace, get each ones resolved classpath and do something with it. The code I have so far looks something like this:

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    for (IProject project : ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects()) {
        if (project.isOpen() && project.getNature(JavaCore.NATURE_ID) != null) {
            IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
            for (IClasspathEntry cpe : javaProject.getResolvedClasspath(true)) {
                // Do something with cpe
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that for some projects in the workspace `IJavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(true)` initially returns an empty classpath. My guess is that those projects aren't fully loaded yet.

I also have a `IResourceChangeListener` which listens for projects opening/closing and does the same thing as what is done on startup. When I close and reopen a project that initially had an empty classpath `IJavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(true)` will return the expected classpath.

Is my assumption correct that those projects haven't been fully loaded yet? How should I redesign this to get a proper resolved classpath for all Java projects on startup of my plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own from the Eclipse JDT source code. The `IJavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(boolean)` can indeed return an empty classpath if the classpath is being resolved by another thread. Adding a call to `JavaCore.initializeAfterLoad(IProgressMonitor)` before trying to get the resolved classpath for a project seems to do the trick.